# Keyboard not working correctly on laptop

Tags: windows, windows-xp, laptop, keyboard, keymap

Something has happened keys "qwertyasdfghzxcvbn" work like they should but "uiop" returns "456*", "jkl"="123, m="0". It happens only on windows and idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have Num Lock turned on, which also turns on numeric keypad emulation on most laptops. Turning Num Lock off should fix this.

Comment: That is right on!

Comment: thx, you helped me a lot. the funny thing that its get "turned on" on startup. I was just downloading some remapping tool to fix it, thx again.